# Nested macro iteration with C preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

With the C preprocessor you can have some kind of high-order macros. Something like this:

```
#define ABC(f) f(a) f(b) f(c)
#define XY(f) f(x) f(y)

#define CODE(x) foo_ ## x
ABC(CODE)
#undef CODE

#define CODE(x) bar_ ## x
XY(CODE)
#undef CODE
```

The output is:

```
 foo_a foo_b foo_c
 bar_x bar_y
```

Is there some trick to nest such iterations, to do something like this?

```
#define CODE(x) foo_ ## x
NEST(ABC, XY, CODE)
#undef CODE
```

So the output would be:

```
foo_ax foo_ay foo_bx foo_by foo_cx foo_cy
```

In particular, I'd like to have the definitions of `ABC` and `XY` independent from each other, so that I can still use `ABC` stand-alone or maybe do even something like this:

```
#define CODE(x) foo_ ## x
NEST(XY, KLMN, ABC, CODE)
#undef CODE
```

---

For the record, here the solution:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq.hpp>

#define ABC (a) (b) (c)
#define XY (x) (y)

#define CODE(r, prod) BOOST_PP_CAT(foo_, BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT(prod))
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(CODE, (ABC) (XY))
```

Yields:

```
foo_ax foo_ay foo_bx foo_by foo_cx foo_cy
```

Comment: Out of experience, I can tell that whenever you are deep down in meta-programming with macros, you are almost certainly creating a poor program design, and it is almost certainly the incorrect solution to the problem. "X macros" and their various spin-offs are to be regarded as the very last resort. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Boost Preprocessor Library](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor) offers several macros that can do this out of the box.

[BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each_product.html) will iterate over the cartesian products of two or more lists encoded in the form `(x) (y) (z)` (which are known as sequences is the library's parlance).

[BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/list_for_each_product.html) will do the same for lists encoded as `(x, (y, (z, NIL)))`.

It's trivial to convert the [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) iteration to a "sequence" like this:

```
#define LIST_TO_SEQ(X) (X)
ABC(LIST_TO_SEQ)
```